# Windows 7 On VMWare Server 2.0 Sound Card

Tags: windows, vmware-server, windows-7, 64-bit

I've dug though the internet but haven't been able to confirm this one way or the other so I figured I'd try here.

I have VMWare Server 2.0 and I've installed Windows 7.0 RC 64bit on it.

Host OS is Windows XP Pro

Everything is working great, except I cannot get the sound card to work. 
The hardware does show up in the hardware list but,

Windows 7 cannot find the driver when attempting to do auto-update and I cannot find anything for a manual install.

Can anyone confirm if this works or not and if so what am I missing?  I'm guessing the drivers just don't exist yet?

Also this is a SF question as I'm begining the testing of Windows 7 on my networks, and issues that might come up (GPO, user's lost in the UI from XP, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I was missing VMWare tools (duh, should have been the first place I looked)

That said the sound driver works well, but the there are still some issues, it didn't seem to like the video driver so I had to install it (the second time) without that.